# CSS blocking apple users forms

Tags: html, ios, css, forms

EDIT: without doing anything, after a week it now works... no idea where this came from but it's all good now !

let's do that short: I have a login form and a register form, both work perfectly on windows and phones, but when an iphone or mac, anything made by apple, is used: they can't fill the form.

So I deleted the CSS of my page, and now they can use it.. I have no clue. Here's the code, if anyone can help me find where I messed up.. Thank you

```
       <div id="loginform"> 
<!-- there is more code as it is added to the page with PHP or not if you're 
connected or not, but I'll only show the HTML form itself, as it is on the page
when a new user comes on the login page -->
            <center>
                <form id="login" action="login.php" method="post" accept-charset="UTF-8">
                    <input type="text" name="username" id="username" maxlength="50" placeholder="Nom d'utilisateur" required autofocus/>
                    <input type="password" name="password" id="password" maxlength="50" placeholder="Mot de passe" required/>
                    <input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Se Connecter" style="background-color: #2980b9;"/>
                </form>
            </center>
        </div>
```

Here's the CSS:

```
input[type="password"], input[type="text"], input[type="email"],         
    input[type="tel"], input[type="number"], select { 
    border: 1px solid #a1a3a3; 
    border-radius: 4px; 
    box-shadow: 0 0 4px 1px rgba(55, 166, 155, 0.3); 
    color: #696969; 
    height: 39px; margin-top: 4vh; 
    padding-left: 1.8vw; 
    width: 16.3vw; 
    outline: 0; 
}
body, html, li, ul, div{
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
  }
body{
  background-color: #34495e;
  font-family: YanoneKaffeesatzLight;
}
*:focus{
  outline: none;
}
```

also two JS scripts:

```
var x = document.getElementById("snackbar");
x.className = "show"; setTimeout(function(){
    x.className = x.className.replace("show", "");
}, 3000);
```

and the header script:

```
function myFunction(){
    var x = document.getElementById("header");
    if (x.className==="topnav") {
        x.className += " responsive";
    }else{
        x.className = "topnav";
    }
}
```

Comment: I dumped your code into a fiddle, and it works fine across safari and mobile safari. Is there any other markup you're using? JS, etc? https://jsfiddle.net/77fspodL/1/

Comment: it works on window's safari but not on apple's safari, but I do use two scripts that I'll add to my question now @pj100

Comment: The markup above works fine in safari on mac for me in the fiddle.

Comment: the complete page is at https://loria.antoinepetitot.fr/fr/login.php

Comment: That also works for me in Safari! and on iOS!

Comment: This is really weird... I'll try it again tomorrow at the school's MAC and on an iPhone, thank you for try it tho !

Comment: So... apparently my friend who couldn't log in now can on ios... really weird, but it now works ! sorry for the inconvenience @pj100 , I'll delete this post or something as it is now corrected